# In Gremlins movie do Gremlins ever turn back to Mogwai?

Tags: gremlins

Do Gremlins ever turn back to Mogwai? I already searched in Google, but I can't find anything. I have not seen *Gremlins* yet, but I want to know before I see it.

Comment: No. In the film, the gremlins turn into corpses. Then they melt. Sometimes they explode.

Comment: Welcome to the boards, incidentally. :)

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is **no**. In neither film do we see any gremlins turning back into mogwai.

Frankly, the only thing we see the Gremlins do is cause havoc and then die horribly, usually turning to mulch or exploding, depending on whether the manner of their deaths is through violence or by exposure to sunlight.

Comment: The rules would seem to indicate that it's a permanent change. Also, Gremlins give birth to other Gremlins, NOT mogwai.